# Executing vi on directory does not list files

Tags: command-line, 13.10, bash, vi

This seems like a new bug (feature ?) that’s creep into Ubuntu 13.10. When I execute `vi` on a directory it doesn't list the files which I can navigate to with the arrow keys; it just shows an empty screen with the message 'Illegal filename'.

Now it's an hassle because I have to `ls` the directory first if I don't know which file I want to edit and then I've got to type the entire file name after the directory in the command argument.

This happens when I go to `vi` the tmp, etc, and even in my home directory which I have write permission for.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour you are describing is caused by a [bug in **netrw**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_use/ZIDW5PcjoZA/S68-gzMvk4sJ), which is the plugin handling the file browsing.

Updating to the latest version of the plugin fixes this behaviour.

To do so, just download the [latest version of netrw](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/netrw.vba.gz), open it in vim and source it. Doing so will extract the plugin into your `~/.vim` directory, where it will be loaded before the system's buggy version.

Download the file:

`wget http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/netrw.vba.gz`

Open it in `vim`:

`vim netrw.vba.gz`

In vim, source it:

`:so %`

Afterwards, close vim. Then, enjoy browsing directories again.

**Update**: On one box, this gave me an error about not being able to *close the last window*. Had no effect on the plugin, which worked flawlessly afterwards.

**2nd Update**: This version of **netrw** expects a version of vim with the *clipboard* capability.

You can check if your version has it by running `vim --version`. The output will probably have `-clipboard` in there, which means the capability is not enabled.

To get a version compiled with clipboard support, install any version of vim with a GUI, which will also replace your normal `vim` with a version with *clipboard* support. I used **vim-gtk** as a test case.

Comment: drc, I'm getting numerous errors in red with the message `Not an editor command`

Comment: Sorry, linked the wrong file after testing it with the correct one. Fixed links in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got that error too about _close last window_ but it works now. Thanks !

Comment: Now I just got this error: _Error detected while processing function <SNR>19_NetrwBrowseChgDir..<SNR>19_NetrwOptionRestore: Invalid register name '*'_ I can `vi` the directory but when I select the file and press enter I got the aforementioned error.

Comment: Seems like this version of **netrw** expects *clipboard* capability in vim. Added a paragraph about dealing with that.

Comment: I'm using vi on a box with limited memory that I ssh into; is there a vim version that has clipboard support that doesn't depend on gtk or tcl ? I would like to keep the text based version I'm using now.

Comment: You can still use the classic text version of vim with a graphical version installed, it'll just be one with clipboard support. So if memory (as in RAM) is your concern, don't worry.

Comment: It seems to be working now after installing `vim-gtk`.

Comment: For some reason this is not working on another ubuntu 13.10 box. I followed the instructions above and the `.vim` directory has been modified but when I go to `vi` a directory it shows an empty screen

Comment: I'm getting this error message:

    ***sorry*** this version of netrw requires vim v7.4 with patch#1557

Strange, because I _do_ have vim 7.4. Maybe I need an earlier version of netrw.

Comment: @CarstenAgger while I can't find older versions on Dr Chip's site, you can probably use this Github mirror: https://github.com/eiginn/netrw/commit/d424dde6ac100a27387173d76f292344f13ba6c4

Answer (score 2):

I tried following the steps given by drc, but got strange errors (perhaps due to lack of clipboard support).

The following worked for me in ubuntu 13.10 docker image, with just a standard version of Vim without clipboard support:

```
vim /etc   # blank screen

wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=21427 -O netrw.vba.gz

# install the vimball
# may throw error E444, but this can seemingly can be ignored
vim netrw.vba.gz +"so %" +q  

vim /etc  # works fine
```

Note that the only thing that I did differently than drc involved me using a slightly older release of the netrw plugin, namely the one uploaded to vim.org on 2014-02-04.

Comment: This method causes error messages to appear.

Comment: Hmmm. This fixed the *strange* errors, and executed without errors. However I'm still unable to get a directory listing.

Comment: hek2mgl, just checked inside this Vagrant VM and my fix seems to work well. https://gist.github.com/dergachev/eaf0e52bd9ebd69e4953

Comment: OK on second thought, the version of netrw I linked to seemed to cause new errors in Vagrant. This version of netrw.vba.gz linked here seems to work fine: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/iEiInCavWKc/8lvamqaVXOYJ